# `doc-view-mode` for PDFs not working

Tags: pdf, docview

For some reason I cannot view PDF files in `doc-view-mode`.

Supposedly if I open a PDF file in Emacs, it should automatically open in the `doc-view` major mode. If it can't be opened in `doc-view`, then there will at least be some error message.

But for me, opening a PDF file opens it in fundamental mode. If I use `M-x doc-view-mode` then the mode-line shows `(fundamental docview)` which indicates that the `docview` *minor mode* is used, as I understand it.

That minor mode claims I can use `C-c C-c` to view the document, but that does nothing, and leaves me in the "editor mode." I've checked the `*Messages*` buffer, and there are no error messages. Here is a screenshot:
[image: A screenshot of the setup]

Here's what I'm working with:

- Emacs 27.1
- macOS 11.2.3 (Big Sur)
- auctex 13.0.4
- latex-preview-pane-20181008.1822

The only discussion I've managed to find about this is specifically for Windows, such as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190882/what-is-the-best-side-by-side-preview-method-for-emacs24-auctex?noredirect=1#comment439981_190882).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `doc-view` tells us:

> Requirements:
>
> doc-view.el requires GNU Emacs 22.1 or newer.  You also need Ghostscript, `dvipdf` (comes with Ghostscript) or `dvipdfm` (comes with teTeX or TeXLive) and `pdftotext`, which comes with xpdf (http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) or poppler (http://poppler.freedesktop.org/).

So check that you have those dependencies installed.

If they are installed, check that Emacs can see them -- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `exec-path` is the list of directories where Emacs will look for executables on the local machine.

---

You may wish to take a look at https://github.com/vedang/pdf-tools as well.  There are some notes about OSX in the readme, so it might work for you if you follow those instructions.  If you *can* get it working, it's much, much nicer than `doc-view`.

Comment: Sadly I can't use pdf-tools, as latex-preview-pane only uses doc-view. I've installed ghostscript using homebrew, and pdflatex --version at command line tells me that I have TeX Live 2021 and it's compiled with xpdf version 4.03. So it seems like I have all the dependencies installed, and still the same issue persists.

Comment: Can Emacs see them?  Check that the executables are available in one of the `C-h v exec-path` directories.  I've updated the answer to mention this point.

Comment: @Thain, as I read code at https://github.com/jsinglet/latex-preview-pane/blob/master/latex-preview-pane.el It can be easily updated to support pdf-tools. You can raise a issue to the author. Or you can learn Lisp and maintain this package by yourself.